# Override Catalog/Product/View/options.phtml template

Tags: magento2

I am overriding Catalog/Product/View/options.phtml template in my custom module but its not working, I am using below code in catalog_product_view.xml file.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure whatever path you have defined in the XML, same path should be available for options.phtml file in your custom module. Please check, I think there will be an issue with Path

Comment: @Nits Path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below code will help you.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::product/view/options.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Please update the file path and name correctly.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magetno setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Please let me know if this will not work.

Comment: Its working i used like this
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
    <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/options.phtml</argument>
                </action>
  </referenceBlock>
 </referenceContainer>